# Ajax/html/php not sending values

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".submit_secure_email", function () {
        var email_one = $("#email_one").val();
        var email_two = $("#email_two").val();
        var ebankpin = $("#ebankpin").val();
        var eusername = $("#eusername").val();
        var dataString = '&email_one=' + email_one + '&email_two=' + email_two + '&ebankpin=' + ebankpin + '&eusername' + eusername;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handlers/handle_secure_add_email.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == '0') {
                    var hiddenSection = $('section.hiddensecure_email');
                    $(hiddenSection).fadeOut(10000);
                    $('.error_one').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_two').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_three').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_four').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_five').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_six').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.success').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.success').fadeOut(2000).show();
                } else if (result == '1') {
                    $('.error_one').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.error_two').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_three').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_four').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_five').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_six').fadeOut(200).hide();
                } else if (result == '2') {
                    $('.error_two').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.error_one').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_three').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_four').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_five').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_six').fadeOut(200).hide();
                } else if (result == '3') {
                    $('.error_three').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.error_one').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_two').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_four').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_five').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_six').fadeOut(200).hide();
                } else if (result == '4') {
                    $('.error_four').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.error_one').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_two').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_three').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_five').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_six').fadeOut(200).hide();
                } else if (result == '5') {
                    $('.error_five').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.error_one').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_two').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_three').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_four').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_six').fadeOut(200).hide();
                } else if (result == '6') {
                    $('.error_six').fadeIn(2000).show();
                    $('.error_one').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_two').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_three').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_four').fadeOut(200).hide();
                    $('.error_five').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php ini_set( "display_errors", 0); session_start();?>
<?php if($_SESSION['email_set'] == true){?>
<h2>You Already have Set your Email Address, You cannot change it or remove it</h2>
<p class="change_link" style="height:5px;width:840px;">
                            <span class="close"><strong>Close</strong></span>       
                                </p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <form method="post" name="form" autocomplete="off">
<ul><li>
<input id="eusername" name="eusername" type="hidden" required="required" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>"/>
<input id="email_one" name="email_one" type="text" required="required" placeholder="My Email"/>
<input id="email_two" name="email_two" type="text" required="required" placeholder="My Email Again" />
<input style="width:100px;" id="ebankpin" name="ebankpin" type="password" required="required" placeholder="My Bankpin" />
<input style="float:right;" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_secure_email"/><br>
<span class="error_one" style="display:none"> Missing First Email</span>
<span class="error_two" style="display:none"> Missing Second Email</span>
<span class="error_three" style="display:none"> Emails Don't match</span>
<span class="error_four" style="display:none"> Wrong Bankpin</span>
<span class="error_five" style="display:none"> This Email has been used already</span>
<span class="error_six" style="display:none"> The system is broken: Report to admin</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Success</span>
</li></ul>
<p class="change_link" style="height:5px;width:840px;">
                            <span class="close"><strong>Close</strong></span>       
                                </p>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

NOTE: BANKPIN IS NOT YOUR REAL BANKPIN ITS YOUR GAME BANKPIN

my problem is the values are no longer being sent to handle_secure_add_email.php they were working before but now their not and i'm not sure why. i've tryed finding a problem in the code but cant seem to find one

Comment: @Satpal, why do you need `form`? And it looks like OP has `form`.

Comment: @putvande, Thats what I am asking Why OP needs `form`. I missed `?`

Comment: im new to ajax, an not to new html/php always used html forms , also Thanks for help problem has been fixed the dataString was wrong, but i also updated it to buddies code below to make it easier, once again thanks for the help!

Comment: use the `console.log()` and post here the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your datastring starts with an &, so i guess it's either that or you should check your developers console if the file you are sending your data to does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery POST data could be sent as

```
data: { email_one: email_one , email_two: email_two,ebankpin:ebankpin,eusername:eusername}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it like this

```
$(document).on("click",".submit_secure_email", function () {

    var dataString  = $('[name="form"]').serialize();
```

That way I wont have to bother with writing the dataString correctly. Let JSON do it for you.